# multiplication compound assignment operator with more than two numbers

Tags: java, operators

I am doing coding exercises right now and came across one task which I don't know how to do, I also could not find any solution on the internet =(

```
For which assignment does the abbreviation stand: a *= 3 / 2?

А) a = b + 3 / 2
B) a = a * 3 / 2
C) a + b - 3 / 2
D) a * b / 3 / 2
E) a = a * (3 / 2)
```

I know how =* and all alike compound operators work with a single number, but I don't know how it works with a complex expression like 3 / 2. IntelliJ IDEA also runs into an error when trying to run "a *= 3 / 2"

Help me please =)

Comment: actually it's simple, the right operand is evaluated first, then a binary operation is performed between the left operand and the result of right operand using the operation in the compound expression. in your case 3 / 2 is first evaluated and then a is multiplied by the result the all is saved in a

Comment: What is the answer then? A, B, C, D or E?

ps thanks for your help =)

Comment: a = a * (3 / 2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

semantic of operator assignment in any programming language is as following:

lvalue *= rvalue  => lvalue = lvalue * (rvalue)

Where rvalue can be any expression, therefore:
a *= 3 / 2 => a = a * (3/2)   -> answer is E

Read more about it here: [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/assign-compound.html](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Eclin/MoreJava/Intro/assign-compound.html)